# Map Data Not Yet available

Tags: qgis

I have been using the Map Bases available in QGIS from Esri. I'm a bit confused about the availability of data in QGIS. Since I have been using Esri Terrain, in ArcGIS Pro everything is fine, the map loads at different scales and zoom levels. However, when I use it in QGIS I try to do the same zoom as in ArcGIS but I get a gray screen with multiple ads saying Map Data Not Yet available.

Can you explain why this happens and if I could fix it somehow?

Comment: What scales are you at when you get the missing tiles message?  In my experience any scale under 1:1000 with ESRI base layers will generate the map data not available message.